# Updating RadGridView after Editing Records in Real Time

Tags: c#, linq, telerik, radgridview

I'm using Linq and a DBML in my project. I fill my radgridview with one of my tables like this:

```
gridTarget = db.tblCustomers;
```

Records will list in the grid. I'm using some child forms to edit and insert new customers. (I'm not doing it via the gridview).
After editing/inserting a record How can I update the grid in real time (after closing that child form)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Before editing the item, find it in the Items collection of the gridview and call the EditItem(item) method of the Items collection:

   ```
   Club selectedItem = this.clubsGrid.SelectedItem as Club;
   this.clubsGrid.Items.EditItem(selectedItem);
   ```
2. Modify the object and then call the CommitEdit() method of the Items collection:

   ```
   selectedItem.Name = "new Name of the item";
   this.clubsGrid.Items.CommitEdit();
   ```

Here is the documentation:
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/managing-data/how-to/edit-item-outside-gridview

Comment: I'm not editing rows by gridview itself, as I told I'm using some child forms to insert and edit database records.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I've updated the answer, but haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks, what is the "new name of item" ??? Just a simple name or what? and what about adding a new record to the collection outside the grid?